# call a particular div id in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to call a particular div based on id in `page_prerender` event but it doesn't navigate to the particular div id.

```
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
```

---

```
protected void page_prerender()
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx#div1");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method to locate the div - pass id of div as argument.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">1</div>

FindControl("div1");
```

Comment: in addition to above you also have to make that div runat="server" so that the div can be accessible to sever code

Comment: Yes, indeed :-) +1 and updating answer

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery Alternatively you can use this to scroll to specific element on page load with animation:
try this on aspx page

```
$(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put `runat="server"`. So, that you will able to access it on code behind

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">1</div>
<div id="div2" runat="server">2</div>
<div id="div3" runat="server">3</div>
```

Thanks